# jQuery UI Dialog and IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI Dialog for a project and having some problems with IE8 (haven't tested it on IE7 and below but did tested it on Chorme and FF).

I use this code in the js:

```
var dialogObj = $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, title: id, modal: false, width: 600, height: 400});
```

The dialog is filled through ajax. 
In IE8 the title is not showing correctly. It's narrow and doesn't show the title's text.

Also I have another problem in IE:
Whenever I press the element that shows the dialog I have an error message:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Wed, 9 Feb 2011 11:27:22 UTC

Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 103
Char: 460
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/js/jquery.js

Which is at this line:

```
return this.domManip(arguments,true,function(a){this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)})},
```

char 460 starts here:

```
this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)})},
```

I use jQuery v1.4.2

If I press the element again it displays the dialog.

The element that shows the dialog is this:

```
<td class="alignText"><a onclick="showDialog('<?php echo $r->Id; ?>')"><?php echo $r->Id; ?></a></td>
```

Note that my page validates.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: its good practice to use `{'title':'helllo world'}` double check that. also jquery was designed to eliminated the need to use "onclick" attribute and also your code is all over the place. Also internet explorer disables javascript on local machines that could be reason

Comment: `domManip(arguments,true,function(a){this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)})},` btw this line looks wrong you have an `}` at the end which does not have a `{`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently I had a defect in my jQuery file. Once I downloaded the file again all was well.